# parse text file and generate new .csv file based on that data

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I would like to parse a machine log file, re-arange the data and write it to a .csv file, which i will import into a google spreadsheet. Or write the data directly to the spreadsheet.
here is an example of how the log looks like:

```
39 14 15 5 2016 39 14 15 5 2016 0  
39 14 15 5 2016 40 14 15 5 2016 0.609  
43 14 15 5 2016 44 14 15 5 2016 2.182
```

the output should look like this:

```
start_date,start_time,end_time,meters
15/5/16,14:39,14:39,0  
15/5/16,14:39,14:40,0.609  
15/5/16,14:43,14:44,2.182
```

i wrote the following python code:

```
file = open("c:\SteelUsage.bsu")
for line in file.readlines():
            print(line) #just for verification
            line=line.strip()   
            position=[]
            numbers=line.split()
            for number in numbers:
                     position.append(number)
                     print(number)#just for verification
```

the idea is to save each number in a row to a list, then i can re-write the numbers in the right order according to their position.
for example: in row #1 the string "39" will have position 0, "14" pstion 1, etc.

but it seems the code i wrote stores each number as a new list, because when i change   `print(number)` to  `print(number[0])`, the code prints the first digit of each number, istead of printing the first number. (39)
where did i go wrong?
thank you

Comment: what if the date numbers in the original format are not the same? like what if there was `43 14 15 5 2016 44 14 16 5 2016` (15th to 16th)?

Comment: `number` will represent each number in the entire file, the first number of each row will be (number**s**)[0]

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this. Write `out` to your `csv` file.

```
with open('c:\SteelUsage.bsu','r') as reader:
    lines = reader.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        inp = [i for i in line.strip().split()]
        out = '%s/%s/%s,%s:%s,%s:%s,%s' % (inp[2],inp[3],inp[4],inp[1],inp[0],inp[6],inp[5],inp[10])
        print out
```

Comment: ugh, the noise! you can just do `for line in reader` no need to `readlines` and `.split()` automatically does `.strip()` along with it, also `%s` could be greatly cleaned up with `format` style formatting instead: `'{2}/{3}/{4},{1}:{0},{6}:{5},{10}'.format(*line.split())`